# Как отследить "натяжение" анимации в RecycleView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отследить значения анимации при конце/начале скролинга.
Для понимания см.рисунок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача, при окончании/начале скролинга применять анимацию к первому или последнему элементу RecycleView. Анимация рассчитывается от натяжения которое на рисунке. Возможно подскажете другой вариант решения задачи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел посмотрев вот эти проекты
https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android
https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor